# How to generate random values that are distant from a list of values?

Tags: python, random, python-imaging-library, extcolors

I have the following transparent images.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What I want to do is to paste them on an image with a background of a specific color. The color of the background is randomized like this:

```
rand1, rand2, rand3 = (random.randint(0, 255),
                       random.randint(0, 255),
                       random.randint(0, 255))

background = Image.new('RGBA', png.size, (rand1, rand2, rand3))

alpha_composite = Image.alpha_composite(background, png)
```

Unfortunately, some of the logos don't go well with their background colors. The background color sometimes comes close to color(s) inside the logo, which makes the logo either partially or completely invisible. Here is an example where the background color is almost identical to the orange color in the Ubuntu logo:

[image]

What I did was to get all of the colors from each logo and save them in a list of tuples like this. This is actually a list of lists of tuples. I've just edited it now to highlight which nested list of tuples belong to which logo:

```
Intel = [(0, 113, 197)]
Corsair = [(4, 7, 7)]
Google = [(66, 133, 244), (234, 67, 53), (251, 188, 5), (52, 168, 83), (0, 255, 255), (255, 128, 0), (255, 255, 0)]
Riot = [(209, 54, 57), (255, 255, 255), (226, 130, 132), (0, 0, 0)]
```

What I want to do is to use the above ^ information to randomly choose background colours so that no part of a logo is made invisible. I'm asking for suggestions on strategies to go about this..

This is the function that adds a background color to the logos:

```
def logo_background(path):

    rand1, rand2, rand3 = (random.randint(0, 255),
                           random.randint(0, 255),
                           random.randint(0, 255))

    png = Image.open(path).convert('RGBA')
    colors = extcolors.extract_from_path(path)

    background = Image.new('RGBA', png.size, (rand1, rand2, rand3))

    alpha_composite = Image.alpha_composite(background, png)


    return alpha_composite
```

```
>>> extcolors.extract_from_path(path)
[((0, 113, 197), 25727), 56235]

# for the intel logo, which is just blue with transparent background
```

Some logos are completely black. The corsair logo is an all black logo with transparent background but the code did not select the right background.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a thre component vektor like rgb is difficult for randome choice. I would convert it to the hsv-color-system (hue, saturation, lightness) first. Then we only need to worry about hue and can use `random.choice` to choose a value from a 1D list of possible values.

```
Google = [(66, 133, 244), (234, 67, 53), (251, 188, 5), (52, 168, 83), (0, 255, 255), (255, 128, 0), (255, 255, 0)]
threshold = 0.1 #No hue value closer than threshold to a logo-color 

# convert to hsv
GoogleHsv = [colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r/255.0, g/255.0, b/255.0) for r,g,b in Google] 
print("GoogleHsv:", GoogleHsv)

# list of possible hue-values that are at least threshold away from all logo-hue-values
choices = [x for x in np.linspace(0,1,201) if min([abs(x-h) for h,l,s in GoogleHsv]) > threshold] 
print("choices:", choices)

h = random.choice(choices)
l = random.random() # random lightness 
s = random.random() # random saturation
# you could also use constants for l,s to alway get a vibrant/dark color.

color = [int(x*255) for x in colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h, l, s)] # converting back to rbg
print("color:", color)
```

Hope this helps. Have a nice day.

---

### EDIT

For your function, it would look like this:

```
def logo_background(path):
    
    threshold = 0.1        
    png = Image.open(path).convert('RGBA')
    used_colors_rgb = extcolors.extract_from_path(path)[0]

    used_hsv = [colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r/255.0, g/255.0, b/255.0) for (r,g,b), _ in used_colors_rgb] 
    choices = [x for x in np.linspace(0,1,201) if min([abs(x-h) for h,l,s in used_hsv]) > threshold] 
    h, l, s = random.choice(choices), (random.random()+1) / 2, (random.random()+1) / 2    
    color = [int(x*255) for x in colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h, l, s)]
  
    background = Image.new('RGBA', png.size,tuple(color))
    alpha_composite = Image.alpha_composite(background, png)
    return alpha_composite
    
logo_background("google.png")
```

Comment: I've added the function to the edits. Can you take a look and see how I can add your logic to my existing code?

Comment: `used_hls = [colorsys.rgb_to_hls(r / 255.0, g / 255.0, b / 255.0) for r, g, b in used_colors_rgb] TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'float'`

Comment: You're dividing r,g,b with 255.0 when r,g, and b are tuples

Comment: thought the result from `extract_from_path` was like `[(0, 113, 197),(...),]`... What does extract_from_path return?

Comment: Oh no. That's not how it is. Check the edits.

Comment: `rgb_list = [x[0] for x in colors]`

Comment: `extract_from_path` also returns the pixel count next to the rgb tuple

Comment: Thanks. Just installed the package myself real quick. I think it should work now.

Comment: I'm waiting... :)

Comment: @wuelfreak Btw, when I increase the threshold to 0.2, it doesn't work. It just reports "empty sequence"

Comment: Yes this can happen, if your threshold is too big. Hue is `0.0-1.0`. So a threshold of `0.2` means that for every color in your logo, all hue values closer than `0.2` are remove from choices. For the google logo, there is propably not much left. So you need to choos a small enough threshold that there is still a valid color to choose.

Comment: Check the edit. The Corsair logo, which is just black with transparent background, has an almost black background..

Comment: Ok. Didn't expect that. Give me some time. I'll look into that.

Comment: Changed the color system and random values for `s,v`. Now ther will be neither compleatly black or compleatly white backgrund. Anything more sofisticated would propably include some heavy math that I am not willing to implement.

Comment: Hey man. Could I get a description for each line of the code? We can take it in the chat if its convenient..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226624/discussion-between-oo92-and-wuerfelfreak).